# Code PTY Pseudo Terminal Emulation by yourself / Control interactive commands in C on Unix

Tags: c, unix, interactive, tty, pty

My dream is to code a pseudo terminal emulation by myself in C on Unix.
My achievements so far:

- I can interact with a shell shell and execute non-interactive commands.
- first of all my program forks to have a child process execute the command whose output is then piped to the parent which writes it to the screen / STDIN_FILENO.

My problem:
Whenever I spawn any new interactive process like a “csh“ shell I can‘t interact with it.
How do you implement the control of interactive processes ?

```
// CHILD
if ((rc = execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL) < 0) {
    perror(“[-] Execution“);
    exit(1)
}
```

Is this enough to interact with interactive commands ?

Thx

Comment: Please add the code you are having trouble with to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "existing PTY functions"?  Do you include `openpty`, `login_tty`, and `forkpty` in that group and desire to implement them, or do you just want to use them?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I‘d like to implement them by myself, as I didn‘t manage to include the pty.h header file ;(; but I‘d really love to understand / implement this by myself ;)

Comment: You can't implement them yourself. It has to be done using the appropriate type of device driver.

Comment: @stark I just did so. Thx

Comment: A pipe is not a pty. Code that checks whether stdin/stdout is a terminal will not work with a pipe.

Comment: @Barmar I know, I tried to implement a telnet like program and searched for alternatives becauses of that code that checks whether stdin/stdout is a terminal. What are other options ?

Comment: You can't. That's why pseudo-terminals exist, because it's not possible to emulate terminals without them.

Comment: @Barmar Well technically it is possible to use pipes and implement your own pty/tty semantics on top. But should one do that? Not if your under a POSIX system (just use the original there), because you'd have to alter the clib to use your ioctl interface, and write a driver part to get real process control. Waah, thats like writing an emulated OS ...

Comment: @jerch If you're going to customize the runtime library or OS drivers you can do practically anything, but I don't consider that generally feasible in the context of answering a SO question.